# How can I have my bach script pull in my EC2 instance IP address?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-ssm, amazon-linux

I'm trying to update my /etc/hosts file with my EC2 instance's Ip address, but I keep getting errors. Here's my portion of the bash script that is trying to accomplish this:

```
TOKEN=curl -s -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"

INSTANCE_IP=wget --header="X-aws-ec2-metadata-token:$TOKEN" -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4

echo "$INSTANCE_IP whatever.hostname.com" | tee -a /etc/hosts
```

When running this, I got an error saying `-s: command not found`, so I removed that from the script and tried again and now I'm getting this error `-X: command not found`. How can I pull in the instance's ipv4 address vis SSM? I'm also using the Amazon Linux 2 AMI for my instances.

Comment: You need to add `` around the shell command in order to assign the result to a variable.

Comment: FWIW, $() is standardized and portable vs backticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is off. Try it this way:

```
TOKEN=$(curl -s -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600")

INSTANCE_IP=$(wget --header="X-aws-ec2-metadata-token:$TOKEN" -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)

echo "$INSTANCE_IP whatever.hostname.com" | tee -a /etc/hosts
```